# Better approach to optimize query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cte

We have a previously designed query that functions fairly well but I am thinking there has got to be a better way of performing the following.  Here is the query...

```
WITH CTE1 ( COL1, COL2)
AS
  (SELECT TOP 10 COL1, COL2
   FROM TABLE 1
   WHERE CREATEDATE < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
   ORDER BY COL2
  ),
WITH CTE2 ( COL1, COL2)
AS
  (SELECT COL1,MAX(COL2)
   FROM CTE1
   GROUP BY COL1
  )
SELECT TABLE2.*
FROM TABLE2
WHERE TABLE2.IDCOL IN
   (SELECT COL2 
    FROM CTE2)
```

So CTE1 can have results like this that require the grouping in CTE2.
CTE1 results look like this:

```
COL1    |   COL22
_________________
10005   |  500
10005   |  501
42344   |  502
12345   |  503
```

SO CTE2 is designed to consolidate CTE1 down to the single row by grouping to

```
COL1    |  COL2
_________________
10005   |  501
42344   |  502
12345   |  503
ETC.
```

I am trying to figure out if I can accomplish this same task without taking CTE1 into CTE2 and then using CTE2 results in the SELECT query.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Imagine that the maximum of COL2 corresponds to 20 different COL1. Which of them will fall into the CTE1?

Comment: @Akina yes, that makes sense. In that case, CTE1 does not return completely determinate results.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question (*and let me know if I have misunderstood your requirements*):

1. Using the TOP 10 rows from Table1 where they fall into some date criteria and are ordered by `COL2`
2. Get the `MAX(COL2)` per `COL1` group
3. Then, select all columns from Table2 where `IDCOL` = `MAX(COL2)` from the previous grouping.

I think this solution addresses all of those items.  Basically, `CTE2` is encapsulated into `CTE1`.

```
--Demo setup
Declare @Table1 TABLE (COL1 INT, COL2 INT)
INSERT INTO @Table1(COL1, COL2) VALUES

(10005,500),
(10005,501),
(10005,521),
(10005,521),

(42344,502),
(42344,550),

(12345,503),
(12345,575),
(12345,575)

Declare @Table2 TABLE (IDCOL INT,OtherStuff varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Table2(IDCOL,OtherStuff) VALUES
(575,'Other1'),(575,'Other2'),(580,'Other3')

--The solution
;WITH CTE1 (COL1,COL2,Rn)
AS (
    SELECT TOP 10 COL1
        ,COL2
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY COL2 DESC
            ) AS Rn
    FROM @Table1
    --   WHERE CREATEDATE < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
    ORDER BY COL2
    )
--select * from CTE1 order by col1, rn
SELECT T2.*
FROM CTE1 c1
JOIN @Table2 T2
    ON t2.IDCOL = c1.COL2
        AND c1.Rn = 1
```

---

Rows coming out of `CTE1` have an additional `rn` column.

```
| COL1  | COL2 | Rn |
|-------|------|----|
| 10005 | 521  | 1  |
| 10005 | 521  | 2  |
| 10005 | 501  | 3  |
| 10005 | 500  | 4  |
| 12345 | 575  | 1  |
| 12345 | 575  | 2  |
| 12345 | 503  | 3  |
| 42344 | 550  | 1  |
| 42344 | 502  | 2  |
```

The last part of the query joins `Table2` with the `CTE1` where only the rows from `CTE1` have `rn` = 1 and `Table2` (IDCOL) = `COL2` value for `rn` = 1.

```
| IDCOL | OtherStuff |
|-------|------------|
| 575   | Other1     |
| 575   | Other2     |
```

Ultimately, you will have to judge whether it is a *Better approach to optimize query*.